# Set number of row to display in Datagridview C#

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Hi programmers out there,

I need to create a Datagridview with specified row to display almost like excel gridview. I'm able to create it in vb,but not in C#.

In C# the row will be only inserted if there's data but not by default. For example i need to create 10 rows by default. Can someone help me with this please. Any help will be most of honor.

Comment: There are simple code converters, that allow you to convert vb.NET to C#: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ Like you said: you can achieve it in vb, c# shouldn't be that hard then.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);
```

Comment: @user3085364, if it answers your question, you should mark it as so. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
public void datagridview_datasource(DataGridView dgv,personne[] _lp)
{
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in _lp[0].GetType().GetProperties())
    dgv.Columns.Add(prop.Name.ToString(), prop.Name.ToString());

int j;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    dgv.Rows.Add(_lp[j].nom, _lp[j].prenom);

}
```